# Capture arguments to expected method calls multiple times (EasyMock)

Tags: java, junit, easymock

I have the following line in my test:

```
Capture<MyType> myCapture = Capture.newInstance();
expect(myMockedObject.myMethod(capture(myCapture)).andReturn(...).times(2);
```

This expectation passes when the mocks are verified but `myCapture.getValues().size()` returns 1. I am expecting a capture for each method call. How can I capture the arguments to both method calls?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is a parameter, called `CaptureType` that determines what gets captured. By default, this parameter is set to `CaptureType.LAST`, which only captures the last invoked method parameter. To fix this, create the capture like so:

```
Capture<MyType> myCapture = Capture.newInstance(CaptureType.ALL);
```